# After removing all objects from the context, navigation property does not work

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have Vulner entity with navigation property CvssVector. LazyLoad is enabled. CvssVector has primary key column VulnerId (not identity).

```
var vulner = new Vulner { CvssVector == cvssVector};
context.Vulners.Add(vulner);
context.SaveChanges();
savedVulnerId = vulner.Id;
var entries = context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(~EntityState.Detached).ToList();
entries.ForEach(e => e.ChangeState(EntityState.Detached)); // remove all entry states
```

later for the same context I ask for the saved vulner

```
var vulner = context.Vulners.First( v => v == savedVulnerId);
var fail = vulner.Cvss == null && ctx.CvssVectors.Any(x => x.VulnerId == vulner.Id);
```

guess what? 
fail equals True!
The only question is WHY???

Answer (score 0):

With changing the entity state you only change if /how the object is tracked from the context. But then querying ctx.CvssVectors you are going to the database which still contains the data.

Want to delete the data or what is your scenario?

Comment: As I understand when I change the state of the entity to detached it is removed from the context (not deleted form db, I do not need it). When I ask for the entity EF should as for it db anyway, especially if it can not find it in local cache. EF returns vulner but without CvssVector.